# How to dynamically change serialized groups in symfony jms fosrestbundle?

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle, jms-serializer

Hello I'd like to dynamically  change the groups of my serialization context.

The code :

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("", name="bap_api_space_query")
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"Default", "space_dashboard", "dashboard_resource"})
 *
 * @ApiDoc(resource=true,description="List all spaces this user has access to")
 */
public function queryAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser()->reload();
    $organization = $user->getOrganization();

    // depending the request, remove or add serialized group
    // for example $view->setSerializationGroups('dashboard');

    return $organization->getSpaces();
}
```

As commented in the code, i'd like to remove or add group in the controller .
Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is pretty easy after 5hours of research :

```
public function queryAction(Request $request)
{

    $user = $this->getUser()->reload();
    $organization = $user->getOrganization();

    // filter spaces where org has an active contract

    $context = new Context();
    $context->setGroups(array('Default'));
    $spaces = $organization->getSpaces();
    $view = $this->view($spaces, 200);
    $view->setContext($context);


    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```